# Is there a way to export pandas dataframe info -- df.info() into an excel file?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a .csv file locally. I am reading the file with pandas. I want to move the df.info() result into an excel. Looks like df.info().to_excel does not work as it is not supported. Is there any way to do this?

I tried df.info().to_excel

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
pd.read_csv("file.csv",sep='|', error_bad_lines=False)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.info()
df.info().to_excel(writer,sheet_name='info')
```

I want to show the dataframe info output in a single tab of the excel.

Comment: `df.info()` returns `None`. You might be interested in the `buf` keyword, see the docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.info.html

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way for me is to get the same information in dataframes, but separately:

```
df_datatypes = pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes)
df_null_count = df.count()
```

Then write to excel as usual.

Comment: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes), df.count()], axis=1).to_excel("info.xlsx")

Answer (score 3):

`to_excel` is a method of the DataFrame https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html and DataFrame.info() doesn't return a DataFrame

You can write the info to a text file like so:

```
import io
buffer = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)
s = buffer.getvalue()
with open("df_info.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(s)
```

You can modify this code by removing last two lines and parsing the `s` variable and creating a DataFrame out of it (in the way you would like this to appear in the excel file) and then use the `to_excel()` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in Python 3.

```
pd.DataFrame({"name": train.columns, "non-nulls": len(train)-train.isnull().sum().values, "nulls": train.isnull().sum().values, "type": train.dtypes.values}).to_excel("op.xlsx")
```

Comment: +1 Million for this Answer!  Thank you!  I finally get it now!  I removed the "to_excel()" at the end to test this and found that ".values" is KEY to removing the Headerless Column-Name Column to the far-left that I cannot control.  Now I may control exactly how my output looks.  All in one-line, with no additional imports, or rigamarole either!  A++!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @yl_low but you could have a more elegant solution as shown:

```py
def get_dataframe_info(df):
    """
    input
       df -> DataFrame
    output
       df_null_counts -> DataFrame Info (sorted)
    """

    df_types = pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes)
    df_nulls = df.count()
    
    df_null_count = pd.concat([df_types, df_nulls], axis=1)
    df_null_count = df_null_count.reset_index()
    
    # Reassign column names
    col_names = ["features", "types", "non_null_counts"]
    df_null_count.columns = col_names
    
    # Add this to sort
    df_null_count = df_null_count.sort_values(by=["null_counts"], ascending=False)
    
    return df_null_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one line code (without non-null column);

```py
df.dtypes.reset_index(name='Dtype').rename(columns={'index' :  'Column'}).to_excel(pd.ExcelWriter('Name.xlsx'), 'info')
```