# copy output from describe and info commands to different dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv file as a dataframe in python. Then i use below two commands to get more information about those files.

Is there a way to copy output of these two commands into separate data frames?

```
data.describe(include='all')



data.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 53940 entries, 0 to 53939
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------   --------------  -----  
 0   carat    53940 non-null  float64
 1   cut      53940 non-null  object 
 2   color    53940 non-null  object 
 3   clarity  53940 non-null  object 
 4   depth    53940 non-null  float64
 5   table    53940 non-null  float64
 6   price    53940 non-null  int64  
 7   x        53940 non-null  float64
 8   y        53940 non-null  float64
 9   z        53940 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(6), int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 4.1+ MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding df.describe, as it's of type Dataframe itself, you can either create a new dataframe directly or save it to csv as below:

```
des=pd.DataFrame(df.describe())
```

or

```
df.describe().to_csv()
```

Regarding df.info(), this is of type 'Nonetype' which means that cannot be saved directly. You can check for some alternative solutions here:

[Is there a way to export pandas dataframe info -- df.info() into an excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221673/is-there-a-way-to-export-pandas-dataframe-info-df-info-into-an-excel-file)