# Exporting dataframe to csv is not working in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to export dataframe to a csv file. SO i did following code

```
import pandas as pd


creditdf=pd.read_csv("E:\Python\Credit Card\creditcard.csv")

creditheaddf=creditdf.head()
creditinfodf=creditdf.info()
print(creditinfodf)

creditheaddf.to_csv('head.csv')
creditinfodf.to_csv('info.csv')
```

Here creditheaddf is exported successfully but creditinfodf is printed but not exported to csv.
I tried same code for both dataframe but creditinfodf one is throwing following error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

What's went wrong?

Comment: [`DataFrame.info`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) returns `None`. Asked multiple times in various formats already https://www.google.com/search?q=dataframe+info+to+csv+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the variable `creditinfodf`, which is `None`. Hence, your `print` does nothing.

`creditdf.info()` prints the string directly, and returns `None`. You also cannot save this string to a CSV directly, as it is not in CSV format.

You could save the output to a file, if you wanted, like this, as shown in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html):

```py
import io
buffer = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)
s = buffer.getvalue()
with open("df_info.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:  
    f.write(s)
```

Comment: Then how can I view my df info in detail?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. Can you please elaborate what you want?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221673/is-there-a-way-to-export-pandas-dataframe-info-df-info-into-an-excel-file